# Content of tags don't appear when convert xml file to array in Zend 1.x

Tags: php, xml, zend-framework

I have a xml file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<zend-config xmlns:zf="http://framework.zend.com/xml/zend-config-xml/1.0/">
    <tables>
        <table>
            <id>product</id>
            <name>Sản phẩm</name>
            <fields>
                <field id="id" show="false">Id</field>
                <field id="name" show="true">Tên sản phẩm</field>
                <field id="price" show="true">Giá sản phẩm</field>
                <field id="description" show="true">Miêu tả</field>
                <field id="image" show="true">Hình ảnh</field>
                <field id="last_update" show="false">Ngày cập nhật</field>
                <field id="sold_qty" show="true">Số lượng đã bán</field>
                <field id="current_qty" show="true">Số lượng hiện tại</field>
                <field id="category_id" show="true">Thuộc danh mục</field>
            </fields>
        </table>
    </tables>
</zend-config>
```

I use `$reader = new Zend_Config_Xml('assets/config.xml', 'tables');` to read this file but field's content (as Tên sản phẩm or Giá sản phẩm) don't appear in new array:

```
Array ( 
    [table] => Array ( 
        [id] => product 
        [name] => Sản phẩm 
        [fields] => Array ( 
            [field] => Array ( 
                [0] => Array ( [id] => id [show] => false ) 
                [1] => Array ( [id] => name [show] => true ) 
                [2] => Array ( [id] => price [show] => true ) 
                [3] => Array ( [id] => description [show] => true ) 
                [4] => Array ( [id] => image [show] => true ) 
                [5] => Array ( [id] => last_update [show] => false ) 
                [6] => Array ( [id] => sold_qty [show] => true ) 
                [7] => Array ( [id] => current_qty [show] => true ) 
                [8] => Array ( [id] => category_id [show] => true ) ) ) ) )
```

**What's wrong with xml file?**

Comment: [Check here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.config.adapters.xml.html) for the xml parsing in zend .

Comment: but in my xml file not exist stagin node ???

Comment: use echo $reader->fields->field;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't really make sense to mix attributes and values in this manner, when using this Zend Config parser. I suggest you either move the value into a "value" attribute, or define all the keys in child elements.

```
<field id="name" show="true" value="Tên sản phẩm" />
```

Or:

```
<field>
    <id>name</id>
    <show>true</show>
    <value>Tên sản phẩm</value>
</field>
```

Normal XML processing APIs - like SimpleXML or DOMDocument - could process your original XML, but this Zend Config parser doesn't seem to be set up to do that.

Comment: Your information is very useful. Thanks so much! I'll do as you said.